# Not able to run another function for another button inside same view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have got the two buttons in the same view one is working  with  the data to show in a label in another view and I have written the function for the button2 (adding another value), when I click on the button2   its not showing the data in view ..... rather it's giving error like this ... http:404 Resource not found error

and this is the view

```
@model MvcSampleApplication.Models.products    
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Valuesadd";
}    
<h2>Valuesadd</h2>    
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitValue","EnterValue",FormMethod.Post))
{
<div>
   <fieldset>
        <legend>Enter Textbox Value</legend>
        <div class ="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EnteredValue)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.EnteredValue)
        </div>
        <p>           
            <input type="submit" value="Submit1" />                     
        </p>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitValue2","EnterValue",FormMethod.Post))
{
    <p>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit2" />
    </p>
}
```

and this is the controller for

```
namespace MvcSampleApplication.Controllers
{
    public class EnterValueController : Controller
    {           
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SubmitValue(MvcSampleApplication.Models.products model)
        {
            TempData["logindata"] = model.EnteredValue;
            return RedirectToAction("submittedvalues" , "SubmitValue2"); 
          // how can we redirect to another view when the button is clicked in one view          
        }             
        public ActionResult submittedvalues()
        {
            var model = new MvcSampleApplication.Models.category();
            string data = TempData["logindata"] != null ? TempData["logindata"].ToString() : "";
            model.lablvalue = data;
            return View(model);        
        }
        // action for second button click 
        public ActionResult submittedvalues2()
        {
            var model = new MvcSampleApplication.Models.category();
            string data = TempData["logindata"] != null ? TempData["logindata"].ToString() : "";
            model.lablvalue = "HIIII"+data;
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

would you pls suggest any idea ..
Many thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form action and action in the controller are not named the same. Also you don't have a `HttpPost`for it

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitValue2","EnterValue",FormMethod.Post))
{
}

//add this
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult submittedvalues2()
{
    var model = SOMETHING;
    return View("submittedvalues", model);
}
```

or

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult submittedvalues2()
    {
        //Do your post actions and redirect to action
        return RedirectToAction("submittedvalues");
    }
```

**SubmitValue2** in the form should be **submittedvalues2**, and add a `HttpPost` attribute on it

Comment: thanks for that but I am getting error like this System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'submittedvalues2' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. when I click the second button

Comment: Well you get that error because your return expects a view thats called the same, you need to specify your return view

Comment: Your action names are a bit messy. I would suggest the following names `SubmitValues`, `SubmitFirstForm` and `SubmitSecondForm`, or just name the submit actions better if they submit any specific like `SubmitImageForm` and `SubmitProductForm`

Comment: many thanks.... one last thing i am not able to show the data that i have entered in the textbox i am able to show the data only this  "HIIII" not "HIIII"+ data

Comment: What are you trying to do? and why do you use TempData?

Comment: i am trying to get the value entered in textbox with string "HIIII" and when i click the button2 I need to show a label in another view .. for that purpose i am using tempdata, as it stores the user entered value, but I am getting null from temp data when i am trying to access it in second http post method

Comment: @pratapk Ok I just need to step out for a minute I can help you out soon, let's take this further in discussion instead

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34149/discussion-between-pratap-k-and-dejan-s)